# store all registers risc-V in memory of a specific time

Tags: c, assembly, memory, cpu-registers, riscv

I am in a project and I need to be able to read all the (x0-x31) RISC-V registers of a given moment. For example, I need to read all registers right after a loop.
I tried with the `asm()` function in the C code but I don't know how to do it. I don't know the syntax.

Comment: You want to store `x0`?  It is the zero register, always value 0.

Comment: i want to store all registers but after i want to filter with those use.

Comment: Ok, well `x0` is not a register it is the value 0.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this could work:

```
struct regs
{
    int x0, x1, x2, x3;
};
struct regs foo() {
  struct regs r;
  __asm__(
      "sw x0,  0+%0\n\t" 
      "sw x1,  4+%0\n\t" 
      "sw x2,  8+%0\n\t" 
      "sw x3, 12+%0\n\t" 
  : "=o" (r));
  return r;
}
```

Extend to all registers appropriately.